# Late evening public transport in Nice

Tags: trains, public-transport, nice

- I am arriving to Nice-Ville on 21 Sep 2015 at 22:50 by train (TGV) from Paris. Is there public transport to my hotel (Hotel Wilson, 39 Rue de l'Hôtel des Poste) at this time of the night?
- My flight out of Nice is at 21:55 on 23 Sep 2015 from Terminal 2. What is the best way to travel from the hotel to the airport in time?

Comment: For getting from the hotel to the airport, I would simply ask for the best way at the hotel -- they may even have their own shuttle service, and in any case they should know what are the good options.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to get from Gare de Nice Ville to your hotel is to take the tram. Since it's late at night, you probably don't want to walk the whole way. But, you will probably have to wait at a tram stop.

As you exit the train station, turn left and a short walk east is the "Gare Thiers" tram stop. The tram runs until just after midnight (at about 20-30 minute intervals at that time of night). Take the tram southbound for two stops to Masséna. Then, another short walk east on Rue de l'Hôtel des Poste will take you to your hotel.

Comment: I had no idea there was a tram. I guess that's what I get for using Google Maps.

Comment: @Rajiv: The tram was pretty new when I was there in 2013. I'm surprised that the schedule is not available on Google Maps yet, but you can see the tram stops.

Answer (score 3):

To get from the train station to the hotel, the most direct way is actually to walk 1.2 km (15 min). If you do want to take the bus, you will have to walk to Rue de Maréchal Joffre (10 min, 750m) and take the N5 bus. From there, you can walk 3 min (280m) to Hotel Wilson. ([source)](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Gare+de+Nice-Ville,+12+Avenue+Thiers,+06000+Nice,+France/Hotel+Wilson,+Rue+de+l'H%C3%B4tel+des+Postes,+Nice,+France/@43.7014971,7.2620485,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m19!4m18!1m5!1m1!1s0x12cdd00630b6fb9d:0x70199f2a745ea0d5!2m2!1d7.261933!2d43.704612!1m5!1m1!1s0x12cddaa422a9da13:0xd3a1384710cd6693!2m2!1d7.2713909!2d43.6993798!2m3!6e0!7e2!8j1436997600!3e3!5i3)

To get from Hotel Wilson to NCE, you can walk 300m to Station J.C. Bermond and take bus 98, dropping you off at NCE at about 20:26. ([source](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Hotel+Wilson,+Rue+de+l'H%C3%B4tel+des+Postes,+Nice,+France/Cote+D'Azur+Airport,+Nice,+France/@43.6797885,7.2006906,13z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x12cddaa422a9da13:0xd3a1384710cd6693!2m2!1d7.2713909!2d43.6993798!1m5!1m1!1s0x12cdd11897ae99f3:0x80532b1cc923c1b4!2m2!1d7.2061525!2d43.659536!2m3!6e0!7e2!8j1437163200!3e3))

To give you other options if you don't want to walk, an uberX would cost 6-7 EUR from the train station to the hotel, and an uberX from the hotel to the airport is 17-23 EUR.